# Text file upload in php, how to do and safety measures

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I need HTML and PHP that allows the user to upload a text file.

I have heard that one should be careful with functions that allow users to upload their own files because people can inject malicious software and code. Let's say my website only allows MS Word on Mac and Windows, what will the code look like and what code should I use to prevent malicious software injections? The file can maximum be 1MB.

This is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="uploadtextfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=
    "post">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input id="uploadedtextfile" name=
        "textfile" type="file"><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what PHP code to use, but according to [W3Cschools.com](http://www.w3cschools.com) it should look something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>";
        echo "Type: ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."<br>";
        echo "Size: ".($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024)." kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: ".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    } 
?>
```

How am I supposed to form the code so it is safe to use and only accepts MS Word files that are maximum 1MB?

Comment: Use Blank Edjok's solution. If you want to do more with file uploading and directory parsing, you could use these classes https://github.com/pbalan/file-uploader/blob/master/src/pbalan/FileUploader/FileUploader.php and https://github.com/pbalan/directory-parser/blob/master/src/pbalan/DirectoryParser/DirectoryParser.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all list all allowed MS Word extensions in an array.

```
$allowedExts = array('doc', 'docx');
```

Use pathinfo to get the extension of the file

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

check if that extension exists in the array you created
If yes then you check the size of that file within the condition.

```
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
  if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) <= 1024)
  {
     // File upload code goes here
  }
}
```

That you should work, i haven't tried it out myself yet.